# value error in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
for rows in capacity1:
     if capacity1['value'] <80 & (capacity1['metric']=='ENT_CORE','UTIL_CPU','ENT_CPU')).item():
         capacity1['root_cause']="CPU"
    elif capacity1['value']<80 & (capacity1['metric']=='FS_CACHE','FREE','PINNED','PAGE_OUT','PAGE_SPACE')).item():
        capacity1['root_cause']="MEMORY"
    elif capacity['value']<80 & (capacity1['metric']=='REC_BYTES','TRANS_BYTES','REC_BYTESS','TRANS_BYTESS')).item():
         capacity1['root_cause']="NETWORK"
    else:
        capacity1['root_cause']= "OTHER"
```

> Error: ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python
>   scalar\

Unable to fix this error.

Requirement : Based on value & metric i would need to assign the root cause.

Comment: please can you  someone suggest me a solution

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with assign repeating conditions to variables like `m1` for better performance:

```
m1 = capacity1['value'] < 80
m2 = capacity1['metric'].isin(['ENT_CORE','UTIL_CPU','ENT_CPU'])
m3 = capacity1['metric'].isin(['FS_CACHE','FREE','PINNED','PAGE_OUT','PAGE_SPACE'])
m4 = capacity1['metric'].isin(['REC_BYTES','TRANS_BYTES','REC_BYTESS','TRANS_BYTESS'])

condlist = [m1 & m2, m1 & m3, m1 & m4]
choicelist = ["CPU", "MEMORY", "NETWORK"]
capacity1['root_cause'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default="OTHER")
```

Comment: when i try to copy the output to excel file i receive the below error:
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0 . When i try to copy to csv file, the output is empty.                                                                   code : capacity=capacity1.groupby(['lpar', 'value', 'root_cause','metric','rpttime','hmc','server']).max()
capacity_output.to_excel("output.xlsx").                                                    csv -> capacity_output.to_excel("output.xlsx").                                              please help me to understand the issue here

Comment: Need `.reset_index` like `capacity=capacity1.groupby(['lpar', 'value', 'root_cause','metric','rpttime','hmc','server']).max().reset_index()`

Comment: @ivvyy - One thing, what column need set to max? Maybe it is problem in your code`capacity=capacity1.groupby(['lpar', 'value', 'root_cause','metric','rpttime','hmc','server'])['column_name'].max().reset_index()`

Comment: thanks .. max is not required.. when i removed it got the below error: AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'reset_index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method.

Comment: @ivvyy - Maybe here is another problem. What need get from `capacity=capacity1.groupby(['lpar', 'value', 'root_cause','metric','rpttime','hmc','server']).max()` ? What is expected output of this code?

Comment: based on the output from capacity1['root_cause'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default="OTHER"), I am using group by for grouping based on lpar along with root_cause & metrics. (for LPAR wise grouping )

Comment: @ivvyy - I am confused. `groupby` is for aggregate DataFrame by columns and aggregate function like `max`, `sum`, `mean`. So if need aggregate column `lpar` by `max` per columns ([ 'value', 'root_cause','metric','rpttime','hmc','server'], need `capacity=capacity1.groupby([ 'value', 'root_cause','metric','rpttime','hmc','server'])['lpar'].max().reset_index()`, for better understanding aggregatting maybe help [this](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/hrojas/learn-pandas/raw/master/lessons/06%20-%20Lesson.ipynb)

Comment: I understood, but same error when i try the code given by you.

Comment: Are data confidental?

Comment: please share me your mail id. for dataset